# How can i parse only 2 keys and their values from an array in a php session to a hidden input and then into jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, session

I have this shopping cart in which i store the data of selected products as arrays in session.

This is what the arrays look like in the session:

```
Array
(
[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => Елемвитал с органичен йод
        [id] => 4
        [quantity] => 1
        [price] => 16.44
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Ритми на здраве
        [id] => 3
        [quantity] => 3
        [price] => 18.99
    )
)
```

Now I have a file cart.php in which i list all the products with foreach. Everything works as it should. Then i have a form below the foreach which takes user input name,address etc, info for the checkout. I use bootstrap form validation plugin which takes the user input and sends it to a php file through jquery ajax and then mails the information to my email. I want to somehow include the information taken out of the session too. I tried to just put a class on a div in the foreach loop and it lists the products like so: productproductproduct. Which is very hard to read. Then i tried with json_encode in jquery and i get this result:

```
{"4":{"name":"Елемвитал с органичен йод","id":"4","quantity":"1","price":"16.44"},"3":{"name":"Ритми на здраве","id":"3","quantity":"3","price":"18.99"}}
```

Which is again very hard to read if i mail it like this. Is there a way to take out the name and the quantity of each array in the session and list it like so: Items: ([name][quantity],[name][quantity]? Please someone help me.

Comment: Can you provide the code of the emaling to see how you construct the mail body ?

Comment: First i take the data in jquery var hiddeninput = $("input#hiddeninput").val(); then i post it in ajax and then in php i do this: $hiddeninput = $_POST['hiddeninput'];

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

$email_body = "A new order was made.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $first_name\n\nItems: $hiddeninput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when you send your mail, you could add the product info like this :

```
<?php
$email_body = "A new order was made.\n\n";
$strProducts = '';
if (isset($_SESSION['products']) && is_array($_SESSION['products'])) {
    foreach($_SESSION['produicts'] as $product) {
        $strProducts .= ($strProducts != '' ? ', ' : '(') . $product['name'] . ' ' . $product['quantity'];
    }
    $strProducts .= ")";
}
$email_body .= $strProducts;
```

Assuming your session variable name is "products"

Comment: Thank you very much guys for the help. jiboulex's solution worked like a charm for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `table` for each `name` and `quantity` like,

```
<?php
    $json = $yourJsonObj;
    $table='<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th></tr>';
    foreach($json as $key=>$value){
       $table.='<tr><td>'.$value['name'].'</td><td>'.$value['quantity'].'</td><td>'.$value['price'].'</td></tr>';
    }
    $table.='</table>';
    // now mail this table in your mail body
?>
```

Comment: If i echo the $table variable this is the result: <table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th></table>  If i echo the json one it's my json object and the value one doesn't show anything.

Comment: Replace `$yourJsonObj` to your SESSION Product Array variable.